# Let $A \subset X$. Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X−A$, then $C$ intersects $\text{Bd } A$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to prove the following:

Let $A \subset X$. Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X−A$, then $C$ intersects $\text{Bd } A$.

If $C \cap \text{Bd } A = \emptyset$, then $$\emptyset = C \cap (\overline{A} \cap \overline{(X-A)}) = (C \cap \overline{A}) \cap (C \cap \overline{(X-A)})$$  By hypothesis, $C \cap \overline{A}$ and $C \cap \overline{(X-A)}$ are both nonempty sets. Now,  the sets $C \cap \overline{A}$ and $C \cap \overline{(X-A)}$ are closed in the subspace topology.

I want to prove $C = (C \cap \overline{A}) \cup (C \cap \overline{(X-A)})$ and also want to prove that the sets are open in $C$.

But I can not do it. Please help me.

Comment: X is a disjoint union $int(A) \cup Bd(A)\cup int(A^c)$.  If C doesn't meet $Bd(A)$ then it is a disoint union of the open sets $int(A)$ and $int(A^c)$

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in C$ then $x \in  A \subseteq \overline A$ or $x   \in X\setminus A \subseteq \overline {(X\setminus A)}$. So $C \subseteq (C \cap \overline A) \cup (C \cap \overline {(X\setminus A)})$. The reverse inclusion is obvious.

The sets $C \cap \overline A$ and $C \cap \overline {(X\setminus A)})$ are closed subsets of $C$. And they are complements of each other in $C$. Hence they are also open in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\operatorname{Bd} A = \overline A \setminus \operatorname{int} A$, hence $X$ is the union of the pairwise disjoint sets $U = \operatorname{int} A$, $\operatorname{Bd} A$ and $V = X \setminus \overline A$. The sets $U, V$ are open in $X$, thus the sets $U' = C \cap U$ and $V' = C \cap V$ are open in $C$.

Assume that $C \cap \operatorname{Bd} A = \emptyset$. Then

1. $U' \cup V' = C$.
2. $U' \ne \emptyset$ because $$\emptyset \ne C \cap A \subset C \cap \overline A =  C \cap (\operatorname{int} A \cup  \operatorname{Bd} A) = (C \cap \operatorname{int} A) \cup  (C \cap \operatorname{Bd} A) = C \cap \operatorname{int} A \\= C \cap U = U'.$$
3. $V' \ne \emptyset$ because $$\emptyset \ne C \cap (X \setminus A) \subset C \cap (X \setminus \operatorname{int} A) = C \cap ((X \setminus \overline A) \cup \operatorname{Bd} A) \\=  (C \cap (X \setminus \overline A)) \cup (C \cap \operatorname{Bd} A) = C \cap (X \setminus \overline A) = C \cap V = V'.$$

This is a contradiction because $C$ is connected.